# POST requests not reaching Node server on phusion passenger

Tags: ajax, node.js, apache, passenger, server

We are running a node server in phusion passenger version 4.0.53.
Website is running and all GET requests work. However POST requests will not reach the node server as they are going to the wrong port.

Node server is listening on port 6969
And Passenger is using Apache default port 80.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957952/cannot-post-forms-using-phusion-passenger-with-sails-js-node-js

Comment: The answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23995887/2984474) refers to a version which isn't released on their page?